# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' error in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, attributeerror, nonetype

I am using Selenium with Python, and I'm encountering an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'" in my code. I'm new to Selenium, and I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Here is the main.py: codeshare.io/OdEMvW works only 24 hrs
Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
# Define login function
def login(browser: WebDriver, email: str, pwd: str, isMobile: bool = False):
    # Close welcome tab for new sessions
    if ARGS.session:
        time.sleep(2)
        if len(browser.window_handles) > 1:
            current_window = browser.current_window_handle
            for handler in browser.window_handles:
                if handler != current_window:
                    browser.switch_to.window(handler)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    browser.close()
            browser.switch_to.window(current_window)
    # Access to bing.com
    browser.get('https://login.live.com/')
    # Check if account is already logged in
    if ARGS.session:
        if browser.title == "We're updating our terms" or isElementExists(browser, By.ID, 'iAccrualForm'):
            time.sleep(2)
            browser.find_element(By.ID, 'iNext').click()
            time.sleep(5)
        if browser.title == 'Microsoft account | Home' or isElementExists(browser, By.ID, 'navs_container'):
            prGreen('[LOGIN] Account already logged in !')
            RewardsLogin(browser)
            print('[LOGIN]', 'Ensuring login on Bing...')
            checkBingLogin(browser, isMobile)
            return
```

I have tried adding a time delay before accessing the URL to allow the browser to fully load, but the issue still persists. Additionally, I believe I may encounter similar errors for other attributes as well. Is there a way to fix all of them at once?

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Addition Information
-Please go easy on me because i am a beginner

- I have the latest python
- I have Microsoft edge and an edge driver which could be the issue but not sure
- One more thing, i fixed an error "browser. Quit" with some Chatgpt and Google search with this

```
try:
    # Code that might raise an exception
    pass
except Exception as e:
    
    print(e, '\n') if ARGS.error else print('\n')
    # Example print statement
    print("An error occurred while initializing the driver:", e)
    ERROR = True
    browser.quit()
    checkInternetConnection()
    farmer()
else:
    FINISHED_ACCOUNTS.clear()
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Sharing the complete traceback might be helpful for someone to answer your question

Comment: The only explanation based on the code you've posted is you're passing `None` into `login` for the `browser` parameter.

Comment: What is a traceback and how would i do the Login browser shift

Comment: I have added the entire main.py if that is helpful

Comment: Would the github repo help?

Comment: Your onecompiler link isn't working for me. Getting a 401 error.

Comment: Here: https://codeshare.io/OdEMvW works only 24 hrs @Loocid

Comment: Debug your program and check that browserSetup isn't returning `None`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765328/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-span-when-using-pytube